Is there something I missed to do, or do I messed somthing up
When I type a letter, it keeps input random letter even I backspace it input a letter. I test to my other terminal it work fine, help me I don't know what happed to alacritty
import = ["~/.config/alacritty/catppuccin/catppuccin-mocha.toml"]

live_config_reload = true

[env]
TERM = "xterm-256colors"

[window]
decorations = "buttonless"
dynamic_padding = false
opacity = 0.9

[window.padding]
x = 25
y = 20

[font]
size = 15.0

[font.bold]
family = "3270 Nerd Font"
style = "Heavy"

[font.bold_italic]
family = "3270 Nerd Font"
style = "Heavy Italic"

[font.italic]
family = "3270 Nerd Font"
style = "Medium Italic"

[font.normal]
family = "3270 Nerd Font"
style = "Medium"

[cursor.style]
shape = "Beam"
blinking = "Always"



this is my config file
this is may alacritty
to fix my problem help, help others with same problem
